# IE explorer issue with linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this background using linear-gradient, it works perfect in modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox etc. However IE shows only white background

```
body {
 font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular',Georgia, Serif;
 font-size: 14px; 
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
 }
```

Is there a way to apply this background inside css and do something special when user is using IE?
Like a conditional inside css? Is this possible

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AsdCr/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my CSS linear gradient to work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924632/how-do-i-get-my-css-linear-gradient-to-work-in-ie)

Comment: What IE version are you using? This is a very significant detail that you've missed from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine in Internet Explorer 10. If you wish to have a gradient in earlier versions, such as 9 and below, you should consider using the `filter` property. You can generate a gradient with those as well.

See: [Gradient Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFCCCCCC, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)13%, rgba(220, 221, 222, 0.9)100%); 
}
```

Comment: How can I accomplish it, putting inside `body{  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#xxx', endColorstr='#yyy');}`

Comment: @cMinor Note also the `startColorStr` has an alpha prefix of `00` to `FF`. So it's not your standard hex value where only RGB are included.

Answer (score 1):

CSS gradients are only supported in IE10.

Earlier versions, including IE9 do not support this feature.

There are several ways around it, but the best is to use a polyfill script such as [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which uses Javascript and VML to implement the standard CSS feature in older IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full cross browser support in IE 6-8 you need to use: 
`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );`

You may find this tool helpful: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ it automaticailly generates cross borwser css gradients.