# IE11 gradient color in background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

So please tell me any trick or IE hack. Here is a simple example in my `codepen` that contains the same issues.

http://codepen.io/ektad/pen/vyQaLm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924632/how-do-i-get-my-css-linear-gradient-to-work-in-ie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make background-image with linear-gradient work on IE 11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980079/how-to-make-background-image-with-linear-gradient-work-on-ie-11)

Comment: Title shortened

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Dupe of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980079/how-to-make-background-image-with-linear-gradient-work-on-ie-11)**

Prior to IE 11,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cccccc');
```

For IE 11:

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
```

That's right folks, we not only have to worry about supporting older IEs, apparently we'll now have to deal with NEWER IE quirks as well...

Comment: @Paulie_D Oops! I just skimmed his question, my bad. Let me edit it for his needs.