# CSS to add multiple color background colors horizontally with hard stops

Tags: html, css

## Question

How can I modify my CSS to add 5 different colors to the background?

I don't want them to fade into each other, i want hard stops.

### Code

I have this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/zZGbYv) that I have started. But here is my basic code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="header-trim"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #946f20 20%, #041b2c 20%, #00adf2 20%, #30bc9d 20%, #7f469f 20%);
```

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PpqLGd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list each color twice in the linear background, like "from 0% to 20%", then "from 20% to 40%" etc., and the percentage values always mean the percentage of the whole distance, so it's:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #946f20 0%, #946f20 20%, #041b2c 20%, #041b2c 40%, #00adf2 40%, #00adf2 60%, #30bc9d 60%, #30bc9d 80%, #7f469f 80%, #7f469f 100%);
```

Here's the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWNbQG

Comment: this works, now I have to research more about IE. so far found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924632/how-do-i-get-my-css-linear-gradient-to-work-in-ie

Comment: that's from 2012...

Answer (score 1):

Add the color values where another color ends. You are basically adding in points where a color starts and stops. And if the starting point and stopping point aren't the same you will get a transition effect.

**css**

```
.header-trim {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #946f20 20%, #041b2c 20%, #041b2c 40%, #00adf2 40%, #00adf2 40%, #00adf2 60%, #30bc9d 60%, #30bc9d 80%,#7f469f 80%, #7f469f 100%);}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmpELj)

Comment: this does do what I asked. But it seems a little blurry where the colors meet.