# Border image: linear gradient not working in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've seen several previous questions regarding this, however none of them work for me.

I have the following divider:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.diver {
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.divider .wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.divider .wrapper .seperator {
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  padding: 20px 0 13px;
  background-size: 15px;
}

.divider .wrapper .seperator--lightBlue {
  -o-border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px)) 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px)) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="seperator seperator--lightBlue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above doesn't render in IE and Edge.

What I've tried:

**Adding a `filter`:**

```
.seperator--lightBlue {
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
                  transparent calc(50% - 1px), 
                  #B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), 
                  transparent calc(50% + 1px)) 1;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#B2E9E8', endColorstr='#B2E9E8');
}
```

And using [this tool](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to **generate gradients**. But this just creates a blue background on the entire div, whereas I just want it on the lines.

Comment: All of these work as gradients. I don't know much about what border-image is but the CSS itself works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924632/how-do-i-get-my-css-linear-gradient-to-work-in-ie

Comment: the issue isn't the gradient but the use of two values with the same color which isn't supported .. so this `#B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px)` should become `#B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px),#B2E9E8 calc(50% + 1px)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: black;
    }

    .diver {
        padding: 30px 0px;
    }

    .divider .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

        .divider .wrapper .seperator {
            border-top: 30px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
            padding: 20px 0 13px;
            background-size: 15px;
        }

        .divider .wrapper .seperator--lightBlue {
            border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), #B2E9E8 calc(50% - 1px), #B2E9E8 calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px)) 1;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#B2E9E8', endColorstr='#B2E9E8');
        }
</style>
<div class="divider">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="seperator seperator--lightBlue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result as below (using IE and Microsoft Edge browser):

[image]